# CMake: how to link an import library with different filename to the library name

Tags: cmake

I'm attempting to link an externally-built library using Cmake to create a Visual Studio solution. For my executable I use:

```
target_link_libraries( exe_target import_target )
```

And the import target was declared with:

```
add_library(import_target STATIC IMPORTED)
```

The filename for `import_target` is import.lib, so I use:

```
set_target_properties(import_target PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "import.lib")
```

But when I generate the projects, my resulting executable tries to link with "import_target.lib". None of the `IMPORTED_` properties listed in the CMake docs seem to have any effect on this (for example, `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` for a shared library). It behaves as though `import_target` were not a target, but a simple filename for a .lib file.

UPDATE: To be clear, the import target is defined BEFORE the executable that is meant to use it.

Also, the imported target does not appear in my generated Visual Studio .sln as a project, which may or may not be significant.

UPDATE 2: On deeper investigation, the imported target IS DEFINED in the scope of the CMakeLists.txt that creates it. But in the parent CMakeLists.txt and other subsequent files, it is NOT DEFINED, in contrast to non-imported targets.

What do I need to do to force CMake to link with the correct filename?

Comment: Are these command issued in the same `CMakeLists.txt`? Please, show the **order** of these commands. "It behaves as though `import_target` were not a target, but a simple filename for a `.lib` file." - Yes, this is very true observation.

Comment: Updated to state that the import target is defined before the exe target: I assume you were thinking that if it was after, this would cause the observed behaviour. They are not in the same file, but in subdirectories called with add_subdirectory from a root CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Also: this is not a duplicate. The answer may be the same, but the question is  different, and no-one searching for the issue I encountered would think to ask the putative duplicate.

Comment: Your question and the duplicate are about the **same problem**: Linking with IMPORTED target which is created in the subdirectory fails: instead of using properties of the IMPORTED target the linker searches a library by the target's name. Of cource, your code and the the other one are different, but they have the same core problem.

Comment: Note, that duplicate is not an absolute evil: this is not a reason for delete a question, as new wording may help future readers to find things. Duplicate mark only prevents answering the question: as your problem is not new, then answers on the duplicate question should help you. If those answers are insufficient, they should be added to the duplicate question (as they resolve the duplicate question too).

Comment: It's not the same problem. It's a related problem, but my question is specifically about  filename vs library name, which is never addressed in the other question or its answers. As the guidelines state, dupes are for duplicate questions, not duplicate answers (https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CMake documentation for [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries):

> The target name has scope in the directory in which it is created and
>   below, but the GLOBAL option extends visibility

Therefore the solution to getting other targets to recognize it is to declare it as

```
add_library(import_target STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may be using the [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) target property incorrectly. From the documentation, this property should be set as:

> Full path to the main file on disk for an IMPORTED target.

Thus, you need to set the **full path** to the library, including the library name:

```
set_target_properties(import_target PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/full/path/to/libs/import.lib")
```